# Scalaz StateT, no access to get / modifiy / put ?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

In scalaz, is there a way to get access to:

```
blah: StateT[Future, state, result] = {
    _ <- StateT.get[state] 
    _ ...
}
```

It seems that only `get` `modify` etc. are only defined for `State` not `StateT`.  I can find references to them for StateT in the source code but I can't figure out a way to import them.  If I switch to cats, I can get access to StateT.get, but I'm in a project using scalaz.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the way to use these operations in Scalaz is to pull the instance of `MonadState` and call methods on it directly:

```
val S = MonadState[StateT[Future, State, ?], State]

val blah = for {
  state <- S.get
...
```

(this snippet uses [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) syntax)